# Arbitrary shape frequency response filter

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, frequency-response, frequency-domain

i want to make arbitrary shape digital filter from equation. that have own magnitude and phase response.

the equation is bessel function. the frequency response is below[image] zero phase and real value

and i make filter using frequency sampling method like this [image]

x : frequency, y : magnitude

and it's impulse response is this [image] x: time scale

because filter don't have linear phase. the coefficient is not symmetric.

in this case this filter is non-causal filter? and do i have to (filter length/2) delay this filter?

Comment: The filter is linear phase and symmetric, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: and is it causal?? and non causal??

Comment: @ggh these words have meanings, and you can show your own considerations regarding applying the definition of these terms to your situation.

Comment: you mean when i do convolution and multiply in frequency domain, there is no problem. that is not non-causal??

Comment: It's not causal and that's very much a problem. Frequency domain multiplication implements circular convolution not linear convolution. Look, what you are trying to do is rather complicated and I recommend taking a class to beef up your fundamental understanding of the underlying math before writing code.

Comment: i know frequency domain multiplication is circular convolution. i skipped zero padding process. when i do zero padding gibb's effect is arised

Comment: Thank you, i will listen your advise